# How to give a certain mob levitation if it is in a 6-block radius?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

(I have the scoreboard set up, use "Levi" for it in comments)

Example: I hold a stick. All creepers in a 6 block radius around would get Levitation until I stop holding the diamond or (Optional) they leave the 6-block vicinity.

I want to hold an item, give the set mob type mobs in my radius Levitation, but only in that radius.

Help is very much appreciated! :)

Comment: a diamond or a stick? make up your mind. xD

Comment: Do you want the levitation to stop AS SOON AS the item is deselected, or have the effect STAY until it wears off?

Answer (score 1):

First, create a new scoreboard objective:

```
/scoreboard objectives add holdingItem dummy
```

The following commands should be placed in <kbd>Repeat</kbd> <kbd>Always Active</kbd> comand blocks:

1. To track players holding your preferred item (I'll assume it's a diamond) you need to give all players holding a diamond a `holdingItem` score of one:

   ```
   /scoreboard players set @a holdingItem 1 {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:diamond"}}
   ```
2. You'll need to reset the score every tick, so the Creeper doesn't go flying every time you get close:

   ```
   /scoreboard players set @a holdingItem 0
   ```
3. Now, all you have to do is execute the command for all creepers around any player with a `holdingItem` score of 1:

   ```
   /execute @a[score_holdingItem_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /effect @e[type=Creeper,r=6] minecraft:levitation 1
   ```

---

#### TL;DR Edit: One-command version

Copy-paste this simplified command into a regular impulse command block and run:

```
/summon minecraft:falling_block ~ ~1 ~ {Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:{Command:/scoreboard objectives add holdingItem dummy},Passengers:[{id:minecraft:falling_block,Block:repeating_command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:{Command:/scoreboard players set @a holdingItem 1 {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:diamond"}}},Passengers:[{id:minecraft:falling_block,Block:repeating_command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:{Command:/execute @a[score_holdingItem_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /effect @e[type=Creeper,r=6] minecraft:levitation 1},Passengers:[{id:minecraft:falling_block,Block:repeating_command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:{Command:/scoreboard players set @a holdingItem 0},Passengers:[{id:minecraft:falling_block,Block:command_block,Time:1,TileEntityData:{Command:/fill ~ ~-5 ~-1 ~ ~1 ~-1 redstone_block},Passengers:[{id:minecraft:falling_block,Block:redstone_block,Time:1}]}]}]}]}]}
```

It will throw a few command blocks above it (one impulse, then 3 repeat, then 1 impulse). To stop it, destroy all the command blocks.

Comment: assuming its a diamond but you provide the command for a diamond sword? ;) also, instead of a boolean like objective, it is better to use a tag instead. plus, you should put #2 either at the beginning or the end of the chain.

Comment: @Plagiatus Oh, thanks for pointing #1 out, I had used a sword for testing as I was lazy to find the diamond. As for #2, it's not a command block chain, so it works :)

Comment: @Plagiatus P.S. I prefer using objectives because 1) the syntax is more readable, 2) it's universal, and if I'd like to add a third value to the system, I won't have to change back. Thanks for the tip, though! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use /effect to add the levitation effect to mob and use @e[r=6] to seelct all entities in radius of 6 to add the effect.

So, `/effect @e[r=6] minecraft:levitation 1` in a repeat command block would work giving all entities in the radius of 6.

If you want to that players are exluded, you should use @e[type=!Player,r=6] instead of @e[r=6].